# Can C++ templates infer return type?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm playing around with templates and I'm wondering if there's any way to make code like this work.

```
template <typename T>
T foo (int a)
{
  return a * 2;
}

int something = foo (123);
```

The problem here is that the type cannot be inferred by the compiler.

I know that this would work if I this used in the above case.

```
int a = foo <int> (123);
```

or even

```
template <typename T>
T foo (T a)
{
  return a * 2;
}
int a = foo (123);
```

EDIT: For clarification, I'd like to know if it's possible to make the code return a double when used like this `double x = foo (123);` and an int when used like this `int x = foo (123);`.

Comment: In C++14 you can write `auto foo(int a) { return a * 2; }` - so long as all `return` statements return the same type, it is inferred from that type. Of course you can only do this when defining the function - `auto foo(int a);` doesn't work

Comment: The return type doesn't take place in template deduction.

Comment: To your question in the clarification, no, it cannot because the function has no idea what you're wanting to turn it into after fact (unless you pass it in as a template argument, of course). My answer below sort of solves your problem, but it requires the argument passed in to be the type you want to return.

Comment: @MattMcNabb even in C++11 you can write `auto foo() -> decltype(body_expr) { return body_expr; }` ... but this will always be `int` anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to infer a return type (although it's unclear what you're going to use that for) is to use a templated conversion, e.g.

```
class foo
{
private:
    int a_;
public:
    template< class Return_type >
    operator Return_type () const
    { return a_*2; }

    foo( int const a ): a_( a ) {}
};

void bar()
{ int a = foo( 123 ); }
```

Disclaimer: code untouched by compiler's hands.

Comment: In this case, it is probably possible to infer the return type [using `auto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944985/is-there-a-way-to-pass-auto-as-an-argument-in-c/60355539#60355539).

Answer (score -2):

Using `type_traits`, you can do all this and more:

```
#include <type_traits>    

template<typename T = std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
T foo(T a)
{
    return a * 2;
}

int main()
{
    auto bar = foo(1); //bar is an int
    auto car = foo(1.0) //car is a double
    auto star = foo(1.0f); //star is a float
}
```

Comment: Not what the OP asked for -- this deduces the argument type, not the return type.  It then sets the return type to be the argument type.