# Is there a way to pass auto as an argument in C++?

Tags: c++, function, arguments, auto

Is there a way to pass auto as an argument to another function?

```
int function(auto data)
{
    //DOES something
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you expect it to be able to do. What do you need that a function template doesn't offer ?

Comment: That's a horrible idea. Argument type is not only for you, but also for others to know what types your function want. Just take 3 sec and write the type, don't be that lazy (or use a template if the type is not fixed).

Comment: Yes, with C++1z Concepts, you can do this :)

Comment: @Synxis it's not always a horrible idea. If the type is complex enough, it might be more readable to replace it with `auto` (assuming a meaningful variable name). Plus, I think `void f(auto t);` is more readable than `template<typename T> void f(T t);`, assuming that `T` is not explicitly required inside `f`.

Comment: @pasbi `assuming a meaningful variable name` This sound like string typing, and hoping for the best (and in practice, you'll always be deceived on this). I also prefer the longer form as it is more explicit about the template; maybe one day I'll change, but only after having concepts !

Answer (score 85, accepted):

### C++20 allows `auto` as function parameter type

This code is valid using C++20:

```
int function(auto data) {
   // do something, there is no constraint on data
}
```

As an [abbreviated function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template).

This is a special case of a non constraining type-constraint (i.e. *unconstrained auto parameter*).
Using concepts, the constraining type-constraint version (i.e. *constrained auto parameter*) would be for example:

```
void function(const Sortable auto& data) {
    // do something that requires data to be Sortable
    // assuming there is a concept named Sortable
}
```

The wording in the spec, with the help of my friend [Yehezkel Bernat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4299382/yehezkel-b):

> **9.2.8.5 Placeholder type specifiers** [[dcl.spec.auto]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#:auto)
>
> **placeholder-type-specifier:**
>
> > type-constraint<sub>opt</sub> auto
> >
> > type-constraint<sub>opt</sub> decltype ( auto )
> >
> > > 1. A placeholder-type-specifier designates a
> > >          placeholder type that will be replaced later by deduction from an
> > >          initializer.
> > > 2. A placeholder-type-specifier of the form
> > >          type-constraint<sub>opt</sub> auto can be used in the decl-specifier-seq of a
> > >          parameter-declaration of a function declaration or lambda-expression
> > >          and signifies that the function is an *abbreviated function template*
> > >          (9.3.3.5) ...

Comment: In gcc, same can be achieved with older versions of the standards (`-std=c++14` or `-std=c++17`) if you provide `-fconcepts` option.

Answer (score 74):

If you want that to mean that you can pass any type to the function, make it a template:

```
template <typename T> int function(T data);
```

There's a proposal for C++17 to allow the syntax you used (as C++14 already does for generic lambdas), but it's not standard yet.

**C++ 2020 now supports auto function parameters. See [Amir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60355539).**

Comment: I wonder: is it the same thing? That is, for each `T` there will be a `function<T>` whilst for `auto` just one, as its the deduction that changes. Or perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: @black: It's just a shorter way of writing the same thing. A different function will be instantiated for each parameter type deduced for `auto`, just as it would be for a named template parameter.

Comment: I thought implicit template parameters were supposed to be constrained by concepts... are concepts now totally dead, or is `auto` used for unconstrained arguments and (someday) concepts for constrained ones?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I've no idea, my supernatural powers are insufficient to know what C++17 will end up looking like. Concepts certainly aren't dead, and might well end up in that standard; but whether or not to allow unconstrained `auto` function parameters is somewhat orthogonal to them.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah that's the idea. Concepts Lite introduces `auto` for parameters as short-hand for unconstrained parameters and introduces concepts for constrained ones.

Comment: It's 2019 today; the standard is mostly ready, `auto` is allowed as function parameter declaration.  This is called 'abbreviated function template': https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template

Answer (score 33):

Templates are the way you do this with normal functions:

```
template <typename T>
int function(T data)
{
    //DOES something
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a lambda:

```
auto function = [] (auto data) { /*DOES something*/ };
```

Comment: Generic lambdas are a C++14 feature.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know when it changed, but currently syntax from Question is possible with c++14:

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93ab03e88f745b6c

There is only warning about it:

> g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
>   main.cpp:5:15: warning: use of 'auto' in parameter declaration only available with -fconcepts
>    void function(auto data)

With c++11 there is an error:

> main.cpp:5:15: error: use of 'auto' in parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14

Comment: As you saw, this was gcc-specific extension, and it was meant to be used only with Concepts TS. With C++20 Concepts in the standard, this becomes a standard feature