# C++ array operator[] not allowed?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, can anyone explain what's meant by this?:

> no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::initializer_list’ and ‘int’)

In this program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void
print_array(const auto& range)
{
cout << endl;
for (auto& element : range)
    cout << element << ' ';
cout << endl;
}

void
sort(auto& range)
{
for (int i = 0; i < range.size() - 1; i++) {
    swap(range[i], min_element(range[i + 1], range[range.size() - 1]));
}
}

int
main()
{
auto arr = { 1, 4, 2, 0, 9, 11 };

print_array(arr);
sort(arr);
print_array(arr);

return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
 g++ main.cpp -Ofast -std=gnu++17 
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void sort(auto:2&) [with auto:2 = std::initializer_list<int>]’:
main.cpp:30:11:   required from here
main.cpp:20:15: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::initializer_list<int>’ and ‘int’)
    swap(range[i], min_element(range[i + 1], range[range.size() - 1]));
        ~~~~~^
main.cpp:20:37: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::initializer_list<int>’ and ‘int’)
    swap(range[i], min_element(range[i + 1], range[range.size() - 1]));
                                ~~~~~^
main.cpp:20:51: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::initializer_list<int>’ and ‘std::initializer_list<int>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’)
    swap(range[i], min_element(range[i + 1], range[range.size() - 1]));
```

Since I said I was new to C++, explaining/demonstrating how ‘std::initializer_list works or giving a relevant link or demonstrating how I could access range[index] properly in this case would be much more helpful than getting triggered and downvoting.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: The operands are `std::initializer_list` and `int`, not an array and `int` Try look it up

Comment: As a side-note you can't use the `auto` specifier in parameter declaration like that. Start by reading one of [these C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to pass auto as an argument in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944985/is-there-a-way-to-pass-auto-as-an-argument-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

I've never used array before, so hopefully someone will correct me if I've done something dumb....
So something about C++ is you always need to understand what type of data you are working with, unless you are just passing it along. So, 1) let me strongly recommend you not use `auto` for the time being.  2) `array` is....kind of a problem for a beginner.  It's sort of like throwing all the C nonsense and all the C++ nonsense at you at the same time.  Try C-style arrays or `list` for the time being?  `list` has a sort function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void
print_array(const array<int, 6>& range)
{
  cout << endl;
  for (auto& element : range)
    cout << element << ' ';
  cout << endl;
}

void
randomlySwap(array<int, 6>& range)
{
  //does not sort..exercise for reader
  for (int i = 0; i < range.size() - 1; i++)
  {
    swap(range[i], range[i+1]);
  }
}

int
main()
{
  array<int, 6> arr = { 1, 4, 2, 0, 9, 11 };

  print_array(arr);
  randomlySwap(arr);
  print_array(arr);
}
```