# Passing auto as a parameter (for pointer to object)

Tags: c++, auto

I have a macro:

```
#define checkAlloc(ans)  checkPointer((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

which is used to wrap around any pointer allocation to check it is valid (used for checking memory allocations on a GPU device side).

The macro is used as follows:

```
SomeObject* myObj = checkAlloc(new SomeObject());
```

and the checkPointer function is implemented as:

```
inline __device__ SomeObject* checkPointer(SomeObject* pointer, char *file, int line)
{
    if (pointer == nullptr)
    {
        // do error logging
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

Now, it is very inconvenient to create a new version of the function for each type of object I might allocate to.  Templates are also not an option since I would like syntax to be clear - i.e. just putting `checkAlloc(…)` around each allocation rather than `checkAlloc<SomeObject>(…)` which is ugly and hopefully unnecessary.

Ideally I would like to change the checkPointer to be:

```
inline __device__ auto checkPointer(auto pointer, char *file, int line)
```

but I understand auto cannot be used for a function parameter yet.  The GPU code supports C++14 so lambdas could be used as a potential workaround from I can read at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945034/7283981 but I am not familiar enough with lambdas to know how to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Template functions have argument deduction capabilities. What exactly is "unclear"? You seem to have few misconceptions here.

Comment: In fact, `checkAlloc<SomeObject>(…)` *would* be unnecessary, as the pointer's type can be automatically deduced.

Comment: A template should do exactly what you want here.  You don't have to specify the type when you call a template unless it is not deducible.  In this case it would be so you can just use it like you would a normal function.

Comment: BTW, `new SomeObject()` would not return `nullptr` but throw in case of error.

Comment: Thanks all. In my case new SomeObject() won't throw as it is in GPU land where exception handling doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the perfect case for a template, I don't understand why you are trying to avoid it:

```
template < typename T >
inline __device__ T* checkPointer(T* pointer, const char *file, int line)
{
  if (pointer == nullptr)
  {
    // do error logging
  }

  return pointer;
}
```

This is very clear and clean and you can use it as if there was an `auto` there:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SomeObject* myObj = checkAlloc(new SomeObject());
}
```

As you can see, there are automatic argument deduction capabilities that don't even require any type specification...

Oh, and notice that I changed `char * file` to `const char * file` as C++11 doesn't allow conversion of literals to `char *`

Comment: Or even `auto myObj = checkAlloc(new SomeObject());`