# Log anything i want using auto keyword

Tags: c++

I programmed a log class that logs messages in color in the terminal. I want it to be able to log anything
I give it to log. I guess templates are the way to go. But can't i use auto as an argument type, then check if it is a string and if not call the tostring method of the object ?

Comment: `auto` as an argument type is just a convenient way of writing a template.

Comment: this could probably help: [Another Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38044251/9233560)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since c++20 you can use `auto` and overload for the other types you want to handle differently.

```
void log(auto test) {
  std::cout << std::to_string(test) << std::endl;
}

void log(const std::string &str) {
   std::cout << "str: " << str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    log(std::string("test"));
    log(10);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could indeed use templates, then just add a template specialization for `std::string` that doesn't invoke `std::to_string`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void ToLog(T t)
{
    std::cout << std::to_string(t) << '\n';
}

template <>
void ToLog<std::string>(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}

int main()
 {
    ToLog(5);
    ToLog(12.0);
    ToLog(std::string("hello"));
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
5
12.000000
hello
```

Comment: Very nice exactly what i was looking for. Thnak you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

No, `auto` needs to determine the type of a variable in compile time, which can't be done until C++20. If you are using C++ standard, either you use templates, preprocessor macros (as some logging libraries do) or directly some `to_string` function before passing the argument.

But, as said, with C++20 it can be done, and behaves like a template.

You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944985/is-there-a-way-to-pass-auto-as-an-argument-in-c#29945047) useful.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: `auto determines the type of a variable in compile time` and why should that be a problem? And if it is a problem the how should templates solve that problem?

Comment: @t.niese By the way the question was asked, it looked like the intention was to accept any argument and check its type dynamically.

Comment: But how would a template help in that case?

Comment: Well, it is the only way that you can make a function suitable for more than one type without using polymorphic classes and that works across all C++ standards, for what I know.

Comment: But your answer reads the way that in the case when `auto` can be used as function argument (since c++20) that it won’t work in the given scenario. And not that `auto` can’t be used before c++20.

Comment: It can also be read like that will give an error, but if it bugs you so much I'll just rephrase it.